# Unity VR self implemented grab function contains activates gravity on Objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

So I implemented my own grab function but if I grab a Object suddenly gravity is pushing it down. Eventhough gravity is not checked in the `Rigidbody`. Here is my Code for fusing the hand and the grabbed Object:

```
if (_isGrabbing || _heldObject)
    return;

Collider[] grabbableColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(palm.position, reachDistance, grabbableLayer);
if (grabbableColliders.Length < 1)
{
    Debug.Log("No Colliders found");
            return;
}

var objectToGrab = grabbableColliders[0].transform.gameObject;

var objectBody = objectToGrab.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

if (objectBody != null)
{
    _heldObject = objectBody.gameObject;
}
else
{
    objectBody = objectToGrab.GetComponentInParent<Rigidbody>();
    if (objectBody != null)
    {
        _heldObject = objectBody.gameObject;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("ObjectBody null");
        return;
    }
}

_isGrabbing = true;

// Create a grab point
_grabPoint = new GameObject().transform;
_grabPoint.position = grabbableColliders[0].ClosestPoint(palm.position);
_grabPoint.parent = _heldObject.transform;

// Move hand to grab point
hand.transform.position = _grabPoint.transform.position;
hand.transform.rotation = _grabPoint.rotation;

objectBody.collisionDetectionMode = CollisionDetectionMode.Continuous;
objectBody.interpolation = RigidbodyInterpolation.Interpolate;

// Attach joints
_joint1 = gameObject.AddComponent<FixedJoint>();
_joint1.connectedBody = objectBody;
_joint1.breakForce = float.PositiveInfinity;
_joint1.breakTorque = float.PositiveInfinity;

_joint1.connectedMassScale = 1;
_joint1.massScale = 1;
_joint1.enableCollision = false;
_joint1.enablePreprocessing = false;

_joint2 = _heldObject.AddComponent<FixedJoint>();
_joint2.connectedBody = _handRigidbody;
_joint2.breakForce = float.PositiveInfinity;
_joint2.breakTorque = float.PositiveInfinity;

_joint2.connectedMassScale = 1;
_joint2.massScale = 1;
_joint2.enableCollision = false;
_joint2.enablePreprocessing = false;
objectBody.useGravity = false;
```

I hope someone could help me out.

I´m using the OpenXR Toolkit and work with Unity 2020.3.4f1.

Comment: Could be that your "hand" collider is colliding (and pushing down) your grabbed object?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was simple. By checking the Hands Rigidbody as `is Kinematic` to true. Because of this the object can only be manipulated by it´s Transform.